# Listen for application will enter foreground on WatchKit?

Tags: watchkit, application-state

On iOS, I have several ways to know when the user launched my app from the home screen when the app was backgrounded:

- Implement the [- applicationWillEnterForeground:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationWillEnterForeground:) in my app delegate.
- Listen to the [UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/data/UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification).

Is there an equivalent in WatchKit? If not, are there any robust alternatives?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The closest you'll find with a WatchKit extension is this set of notifications that were introduced in iOS 8.2:

```
NSExtensionHostWillEnterForegroundNotification
NSExtensionHostDidEnterBackgroundNotification
NSExtensionHostWillResignActiveNotification
NSExtensionHostDidBecomeActiveNotification
```

You can read more about these notifications in the [NSExtensionContext documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSExtensionContext_Class/).